# Creating 100 subdomain on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, subdomain, admin

I setup the  `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and followed the normal setup procedure
but still I am not able to access subdomain.
I guess its because my subdomain name is only added in /etc/hosts not in DNS server. Am I correct ?
Do I need to make entry in DNS server for each subdomain name ? or only main domain name in DNS server  is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In what /etc/hosts you have added the subdomain? If apache is on localhost and you use the browser on the same machine it's enought. If your are using a machine for the webserver and another for the browser you must add the configuration in both /etc/hosts.. and so on for other machine. If you want give to everyone the access to this subdomain you must set a CNAME on your dns.

Comment: I have added subdomain in server side /etc/hosts not in browser side machine.  Do  I need to add subdomain in both server and client /etc/hosts to allow  browser from one machine to access server machine ?  and if I do this Iclient will be able to access to server subdomain right?  and is it ok to put *.sub.domain.com in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: yes you need to add it on client and server side and no you can't do *.sub.domain.com. To me doesn't work. On [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/265396) i read that you can use a client side  proxy to manage it. But i never tryed it.